# gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found while installing brave browser

Tags: command-line, software-installation, ssl, pgp, openpgp

I've executed the below command line:

```
curl -s https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -
```

I've got the following error message:

> gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

How can I solve it?

Comment: did any of the below answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

> As @FrancoisMarier mentioned in the comment below, it is better not to
>   access sites without valid access key.
>
> However, if you are sure that you know what you are doing, and wish to
>   access the site without valid access key, you can use the `--insecure`
>   or `--no-check-certificate` flags.

---

In order to solve the error:

> gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

1. You can download the file using *insecure* way using `-k` or `--insecure`

   ```
   curl -k -s https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -
   ```
2. You can also download the file using `wget` with the `--no-check-certificate` option:

   ```
   wget --no-check-certificate -qO - https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -
   ```

**[curl manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/curl.1.html) explain this option:**

> -k, --insecure
>                     (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections  and
>                     transfers.  All  SSL  connections  are  attempted to be made secure by using the CA
>                     certificate bundle installed by default.  This  makes  all  connections  considered
>                     "insecure" fail unless -k, --insecure is used.
>
> See        this        online       resource       for       further       details:
>                     http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: I would advise against this solution. If there's a problem with the signing key, you should contact Brave immediately. By turning off certificate verification, you can no longer be sure that you are getting the right software.

Comment: @FrancoisMarier - thanks for your comment, I've updated my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today with Brave using their posted instructions. It seems that the `brave-core.asc` file is non-existent at the address they have listed. Installing the Beta version instead (instructions on the same page) works fine for me.

The `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found` error is because the `brave-core.asc` file downloaded via curl is a zero-byte (empty) file, and there is actually no OpenPGP data inside it.

Update (2020-01-09): it looks like Brave has fixed the link for the release version, and the `brave-core.asc` file is now available at the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

We had a short-lived outage in January and so that probably explains what you saw there. In general though, if you run into problems with the signing key, you are more likely to get a response if you ask your question on the [official support forum](https://community.brave.com/).

If you run into a *security error* while trying to install or upgrade Brave, then feel free to email us at `security@brave.com`.